# How to use C# to clone an array of structure into a binary file?

Tags: c#, arrays, binary

In VB.net, I can use fileput to store an array of structure in a binary file, and fileget to retrieve the array of structure.
Can C# use the above same functions to do the job?
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309525/in-c-how-can-i-reinterpret-byte-as-t-where-t-is-a-struct/70309604#70309604 - My answer demonstrates reading and writing an array of structs from and to a stream.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.